# Query a tabla con registros con periodos de vigencia

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla pedidos, en donde se registran los pedidos que realizan las escuelas. Estos pedidos salen con el nombre del director de la escuela.

El modelo que tengo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esa parte del modelo, puedo saber qué Escuela hizo el pedido y qué Director lo generó.

El problema que me surje es que los directores cambian de escuela cada cierto tiempo, por lo que la relación Escuelas-Directores depende de la fecha, por lo que cuando una Escuela realiza un pedido, se debería obtener el Director que está vigente en ese momento, para que el pedido salga con su nombre.

Tengo claro que debería agregar dos campos, fechaDesde y fechaHasta, para lo cual creo una tabla relación entre Directores y Escuelas, es decir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es si en esta tabla de relación directoresEscuelas, debería tener una Primary Key ?

En base a lo que me comentaron, voy a implementar el siguiente diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este diseño, me permite responder a dos momentos de ejecución.

Cuando se está generando un pedido, las tablas Directores-directoresEscuelas-Escuelas, me sirven para obtener Quién es el director de una escuela en la fecha que se realiza la solicitud, pues con el idescuela y la fecha actual entre las fechaDesde y fechaHasta, me permiten obtener el iddirector vigente en la fecha actual. El id de esa relación (iddirectorescuela) queda grabada en la tabla pedidos.

Cuando se realiza una consulta histórica sobre un pedido específico, como el iddirectorescuela quedó grabado en el pedido, con la relación directorescuela se puede obtener los datos del director en el momento que se hizo el pedido.

Aunque el director vuelva, se vaya, vuelva, se vaya, etc, de una escuela, cada alta o baja quedará registrada en la tabla directorescuela con la fecha de vigencia desde y hasta.

Cuando se da de alta el director, la fechaDesde será la fecha actual de alta y la fechaHasta, pondré una fecha comodín, algo como '30-12-3000' y cuando el director se vaya, se dará de baja, actualizando la fechaDesde del registro anterior con la fecha del día que se va.

Según veo, el manejar fechas de alta y bajas en una tabla relación, me permite mantener información histórica y accederla en forma unívoca.

Comment: Saludos. Yo, particularmente considero que sí; esto por que (quizas no ocurra en el mundo real) puede durante las pruebas chequen el escenario de si un mismo profesor es director de escuela X, lo cambian de escuela y luego vuelve a ser asignado como director de esa misma escuela.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @RobertoLeOr, modifiqué el modelo y creo que como quedó, cubre lo que me mencionas.

Answer (score 0):

Coincido con Junco. Ademas eliminaria las fechas y `idDirector` de la escuela. Ya los tienes relacionado con `directoresEscuelas`. Ademas eliminaria las `idEscuela` e `idDirector` de los pedidos y añadiria la `idDirectoresEscuelas` y una fecha del pedido.

Comment: Muchas gracias @JJP por tus comentarios. Modifiqué el diseño y creo que responde a los dos momentos de ejecución.